# Escape an escape in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping

I'm building out lucene queries and having issues querying strings that contain escaped values (e.g., `test\"string`)

My issue is when I try to encode or replace it, it ignores the escaped values.

```
let string = `some test\"string` //yes, we're looking for \"
let newstring = string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
let encstring = encodeURIComponent(newstring)
```

How can I encode any escaped characters including the backslashes?
My expected output should be:

```
some%20test%5C%22string
```

But I'm getting

```
some%20test%22string //missing the backslash
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no backslash in `` `some test\"string` ``, there's only the quote (that was unnecessarily escaped using a backslash). It's exactly the same string as `` `some test"string` `` - that's why your regex doesn't find anything to replace.

So you either have to change the regex to search for quotes to escape, or you have to put the backslash in the string in the first place (and then no longer need to escape it):

```
`some test\\"string`
String.raw`some test\"string`
"some test\\\"string"
`some test"string`.replace(/"/g, "\\$&")
"some test\"string".replace(/"/g, "\\$&")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the data that I'm searching through has all kinds of weird stuff like that, and the values I need to query are the exact string, but encoded.